# JSON use alternative file path

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a way for a JSON object to check a file path and if it doesn't exist use a default path?

Ultimately I need it to do this: (logical representation)

```
{  
   "filePath": "path/to/custom" ? "path/to/custom" : "path/to/default" 
}
```

Comment: JSON is only a format for storing data. It doesn't have syntax for operations. What does your question have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: No. Json is not a logical code language. Its just a data format. You need to use another language that creates the JSON-object to do this for you. Either Javascript, PHP, C#, Java etc.

Comment: JSON is a data-interchange format. It doesn't *do* anything, it just represents data.

Comment: Also this sounds like an xy problem. What is the higher level problem you are trying to solve? Please provide more context.

Comment: @FelixKling, Thanks, I added JavaScript in case this was something that needed to be done through JS as Ole stated.  Context: I have a config file that needs to provide the reference to a generated file, but that file may or may not be there. If it's not it needs to choose the path to a default file we know exists. Looks like this need to be handled outside of the JSON object per the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the different paths to an array. Like:

```
{
    "filePath": [..., ...]
}
```

or if you need just two paths:

```
{
    "filePath": {custom: ..., default: ...}
}.
```

You have to find a way to check, if the path exists.